# Print errors for Brother HL-5340D on Ubuntu 12.10 / 13.04

Tags: printing, brother

Our printer (Brother HL-5340D) does not print correctly on Ubuntu 12.10/13.04. Almost every print-job looks like this:

[example of faulty print job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a1dG.png)

As you can see, the printer is possessed :). Despite that, everything works fine on 12.04 and older versions. The drivers (Brother HL-5350 DN Br-Script3) are the same for 12.04 and 12.10/13.04.

Test-pages are printed correctly. Sometimes we also get an extra page that looks like this:

```
ERROR:
undefined
OFFENDING COMMAND:
....Undefined
STACK:
(numbers)
```

How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install LPR driver:

http://www.brother.com/cgi-bin/agreement/agreement.cgi?dlfile=http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/hl5340dlpr-2.0.3-1.i386.deb&lang=English_lpr

and install the cupswrapper driver:

http://www.brother.com/cgi-bin/agreement/agreement.cgi?dlfile=http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/cupswrapperHL5340D-2.0.4-1.i386.deb&lang=English_gpl

All the information is available on the official web:

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#HL-5340D

Answer (score 1):

I was hitting this exact same issue today when trying to print PDFs. I was also using the `Br-Script3` driver but switched to the `Brother MFC9840CDW Foomatic/Postscript` driver.

I would rather use the (correct) former driver, but it appears to be an issue that has not been resolved and this is an adequate workaround for my purposes.

Comment: This fix did not work :(.

Answer (score 1):

For us on Ubuntu 12.10 it wouldn't print anything (not even the test page) and would blink red/orange the bottom 4 lights when we tried to print. We resolved it by switching drivers to a generic driver (the Linux ones listed on Brother's website didn't appear to work, maybe I messed up the install) and even double-side printing works now! Ubuntu seems to recognize the printer and automatically add using the Br-Script3 driver.

To change it, since I have Cinnamon, I went into `cinnamon-settings` (`gnome-control-center` does NOT appear to let you change the driver associated with an automatically recognized printer), **Printers > HL-5340D** right click, **Printer Properties > Settings, Make and Model, Change > Select Printer from Database, Generic, Forward > PCL 6/PCL SL > Generic PCL 6/PCL XL Printer -CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.9**.

I have included a screenshot of the appropriate settings. Cinnamon Settings is what you want, on the left/bottom. Gnome-control-center on the right doesn't work.

[image: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-3a9G73E4Jlc/Us7a5Yf7gpI/AAAAAAAA9I4/CA6U8rb6htc/w1168-h657-no/Screenshot+from+2014-01-09+12%253A13%253A29.png]

Edit: my friend got it to work without Cinnamon by
going to `localhost:631` and then roughly do the same procedure (select the printer, **Administration > Modify Printer**, ...).

Comment: This fix did not work for me :(.

Comment: The web UI worked for me, the Gnome one seems to hang indefinitely while adding a printer. There are some packages with Brother laser drivers and ppd's that may contain the particular model.

Answer (score 0):

I have the HL-5250DN, and I've run across this myself.  It's a pain.  I haven't had the time (and I usually just use my windows box instead), but you might try one of the HP PCL drivers instead.  They've worked for me on Windows when I've had a PC that didn't have the brother drivers installed, and not a lot of time.  The older the PCL driver is, the better your chances will be (but fewer features will be supported)